# DynamoDB table to Hive when some column have couple of different data types?

Tags: hive, amazon-dynamodb, type-conversion

Hi I am trying to create external table from Dynamo in Hive and save it on s3 as parquet files. I encountered a problem with one column **value** that have items with different data types (sometimes string, sometimes number and sometimes array of strings/numbers). Because of that I cannot know what data type that column should be - if I set it to string items with number or array will have Null value for that attribute.

Does anyone know how can I create table that converts all these types to string? Will I have to write custom SerDe?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using this Storage Handler org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler 
if so, then take a look this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.ExternalTableForDDB.html

In particular this section:

Note: The following DynamoDB data types are not supported by the DynamoDBStorageHandler class, so they cannot be used with dynamodb.column.mapping

```
Map
List
Boolean
Null
```

Then if you have a DynamoDB column with any of above datatypes you hive column value always will be NULL.